# How to find and replace a div in a text response from AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I be able to find and replace a div (or other tag) in HTML which is saved as text in a  variable? I get the HTML as a text response from ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'page.pgp',
    success: function(result) {
    // here I want to find certain HTML tag
        // in result variable and replace it with something else
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn your HTML response into DOM elements stored in a jQuery object by wrapping it with `$()`. Then just [use `.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to locate what you're looking for, and [use `.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) to remove it and replace with new content.

This example will replace *all* `<div>` elements found. You may need to make the selector more specific.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'page.pgp',
    success: function(result) {
        var $result = $(result);
        $result.find( 'div' ).replaceWith('<span>something else</span>');
        $result.appendTo('body');
    }
});
```

Note that if the `<div>` you're looking for is at the top level of the elements, you'll need to [use `.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead.

The example the [uses `.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) to insert the result.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the response in jQuery and traverse it like always:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'page.pgp',
    success: function(result) {
        result = $(result).find('.your-selector').replaceWith('<div></div>').end().html();
    }
});
```

Note that you do not need to use `.html()` afterwards.

Comment: Just FYI, `result` will contain the HTML content of the `.your-selector` you were replacing because `replaceWith()` returns the one that was replaced. :o)

Answer (score 0):

If your response is returning a valid HTML structure then you should be able to throw it into the jQuery factory function $(result).

```
$(result).find('div') // do something
```